# PHPMAILER SOLO MANDA EMAIL DE PRIMER REGISTRO DE TABLA

Tags: php, phpmailer

a ver si me podeis ayudar ya que es un poco raro lo que me pasa. Tengo una tabla donde pongo registros de personas y en la linea de cada registro tengo un boton que abre un modal y mande un email de los datos de ese registro a la direccion que yo selecciono.

El caso curioso es que funciona con el registro mas antiguo que tenga la tabla, ya que en cuando elimino el registro siguiente registro mas viejo funciona.

Os paso codigo del modal y del codigo de php mailer a ver si podeis hecharme un cable. Este es el modal que muestra los datos para que elija el email y los mande:

```
 <div class="card-body">
            <table id="example2" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="50%">
                    <col width="25%">
                    <col width="25%">
                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: left">Nombre trab.</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Fecha cita</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $contadorcitas = 0;
                    foreach ($citasrm as $citasrm_dato) {
                        $contadorcitas = $contadorcitas + 1;
                        $id_citarm = $citasrm_dato['id_citarm'];
                    ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: left"><?php echo $citasrm_dato['nombre_tr']; ?></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $newdate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($citasrm_dato['fecha_crm'])) ?></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center">
                                <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block" role="group" aria-label="Basic mixed styles example">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" title="Email Cita RM" data-target="#modal-emailcita<?php echo $id_citarm; ?>"><i class="fa-regular fa-envelope"></i></i></button>
                                    <a href="update.php?id_usuario=<?php echo $id_usuario ?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" title="Editar"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a>
                                    <a href="../../app/controllers/reconocimientos/delete_cita.php?id_citarm=<?php echo $id_citarm; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-font-size" onclick="return confirm('¿Realmente desea eliminar el registro?')" title="Eliminar cita RM"><i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i> </a>

                                </div>
                            </td>


<div class="modal fade" id="modal-emailcita<?php echo $id_citarm; ?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:gold">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-emailcita" style="color: black;"><i class="bi bi-person-lines-fill"></i>Recon. Médico - <?php echo $citasrm_dato['nombre_tr'] ?> - Detalles</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" style="color:black;" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">

   <form action="../../app/controllers/reconocimientos/enviar_email.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                                <div class="row">

                                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                                            <label for="nombre_tr" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Nombre</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                                <input type="text" id="nombre_tr" name="nombre_tr" value="<?php echo $citasrm_dato['nombre_tr'] ?>" class="form-control" disabled>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                                            <label for="dni_tr" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">DNI/NIE</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                                <input type="text" id="dni_tr" name="dni_tr" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $citasrm_dato['dni_tr'] ?>" disabled>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                                            <label for="categoria_tr" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Puesto</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                                <input type="text" id="categoria_tr" name="categoria_tr" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $citasrm_dato['nombre_cat'] ?>" disabled>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                                            <label for="centro_tr" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">Centro</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                                <input type="text" id="centro_tr" name="centro_tr" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $citasrm_dato['nombre_cen'] ?>" disabled>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                                            <label for="centro_tr" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Empresa</label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                                <input type="text" id="razonsocial_emp" name="razonsocial_emp" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $citasrm_dato['razonsocial_emp'] ?>" disabled>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>




                                                    </br>
                                                    <hr>

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label for="">Destinatario email</label>
                                                            <select name="destinatario" id="destinatario" class="form-control">
                                                                <?php
                                                                foreach ($emailsinteres_datos as $emailsinteres_dato) { ?>
                                                                    <option value="<?php echo $emailsinteres_dato['email_ei']; ?>"><?php echo $emailsinteres_dato['nombre_ei'] ?> | <?php echo $emailsinteres_dato['email_ei'] ?></option>
                                                                <?php
                                                                }
                                                                ?>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                </br>
                                                <hr>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="">Anotaciones / restricciones</label>
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="anotaciones_crm" name="anotaciones_crm" rows="6"></textarea>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="modal-footer">

                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="bi bi-envelope-arrow-up"></i></i> Enviar</button>

                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>



                                <!--fin modal-->
```

Ahora os paso el controlador del phpmailer:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '../emails/Exception.php';
require '../emails/PHPMailer.php';
require '../emails/SMTP.php';

$nombre_tr = $_POST['nombre_tr'];
$dni_tr = $_POST['dni_tr'];
$categoria_tr = $_POST['categoria_tr'];
$centro_tr = $_POST['centro_tr'];
$razonsocial_emp = $_POST['razonsocial_emp'];
$destinatario = $_POST['destinatario'];
$anotaciones_crm = $_POST['anotaciones_crm'];


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                     
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                   
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                  
    $mail->Username   = 'emilivives@gmail.com';                   
    $mail->Password   = '********';                              
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                   
   
 //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('emilivives@gmail.com');
    $mail->addAddress($destinatario);     //Add a recipient
    //Name is optional

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';                            
    $mail->Subject = 'SOLICITUD CITA RECONOCIMIENTO MÉDICO';
    $mail->Body    = "<html>
    <body>
    <h5>
    <br>
   
    EMPRESA:$razonsocial_emp
    NOMBRE TRABAJADOR: $nombre_tr
    DNI: $dni_tr
    Puesto: $categoria_tr
$anotaciones_crm
    </body>
    </html>";

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Email enviado correctamente';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error al enviar el email: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: hola, el codigo html que has compartido no hace nada que tenga que ver con el envio de correos...

Comment: Hola, como comento la primera parte es un modal que envia las variables al controlador que esta mas abajo (no se como ponerlo separado)

Comment: ok ya te corregi el formato de la pregunta pero aun me quedan dudas si bien tienes un modal y en el modal envias variables al backend ... no me queda claro cual es la tabla o como extraes de la tabla los datos ... eso seguro que lo has colocados por que no lo encuentro ...

Comment: Ok, la tabla no la puse, puedo ponerla antes del modal para que la veais. Si  Por otra parte, como haceis para poner los codigos separados (la correccion de formato que me has hecho)?.

Comment: Tu pregunta  no es clara. ¿Cómo estás mandando todos esos datos que luego intentas recoger por POST en el controlador? ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_POST);` en el controlador? ¿Qué quieres decir con *El caso curioso es que funciona con el registro mas antiguo que tenga la tabla, ya que en cuando elimino el registro siguiente registro mas viejo funciona.*? A veces **el problema es no saber explicar el problema**.

Comment: Como bien apuntas no indicaba el formulario, modifico codigo con lo hecho y ahora me comenta que " Undefined array key "nombre_tr" "

Comment: deberia realizar un consulta de datos de tabla para pasarlo, veo que si puedo resolverlo. Gracias @A.Cedano ya que una simple connotacion me he replanteado el tema ya que procedia incorrectamente. Os mantego informados

Comment: Es normal que tengas un *`Undefined index`*  en `nombre_tr`, si observas, has puesto que ese elemento sea **`disabled`**, y [la especificación](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/input.html) dice que los elementos marcados como `disabled` **no se envían con el formulario**: *The disabled attribute is used to make the control non-interactive and **to prevent its value from being submitted**.* Puedes marcarlos como `readonly`, o hacerlo parecer como desactivado mediante `.css`.

Comment: GRACIAS @A.Cedano . has dado en el clavo.

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Saludos.